# Call Objective C method with blocks from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am implementing Matrix messaging into my iOS app using their MatrixKit framework which I added to my project via Cocoapods. I have everything working except for one final issue: one of the provided methods isn't recognized in my Swift file. The MXSession.h file lists a method:

```
- (void)start:(void (^)(void))onServerSyncDone
  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

which is used to start an MXSession.  I need to call this method from my Swift class, and I have tried to following to no avail:

```
session.start({
   //success 
}, failure: {
   //failure   
})
```

The compiler complains that `Value of type 'MXSession' has no member 'start'` when it clearly does.  Also, strangely, I am able to access other methods in MXSession, such as:

`- (void)resume:(void (^)(void))resumeDone;`

The following:

```
session.resume {
    //resumed successfully
}
```

works perfectly.  I am not too comfortable with closures in swift, am I simply making a syntax error?  I have tried everything and can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course I solved it the instant I posted this question.  Apparently the `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` macro appends two underscores to the beginning of the method for use in swift.  The following code compiles:

```
session.__start({
    //success
}, failure: { error in
    //failure
})
```

Comment: Samuel you should make it as answer.